# PHP CLI not loading IMAP extension

Tags: php, imap, php-cli

When I try to run a script that uses `imap` in my browser, it works fine (it is loaded from a Ubuntu 14.04 server on my network with the extension installed). However, when I try to use PHP CLI on said server, it doesn't load `imap`.

I wrote a simple script to check loaded extensions, using `get_loaded_extensions()`, and it taught me 2 things:

- PHP CLI had 50 extensions, while running it through my web browser had 51.
- Another extension I manually declared in my `apache2/php.ini` (`imagick.so`) was being loaded in both CLI and browser

Why is this happening, and how can I have all 51 extensions loaded in both CLI and browser?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are separate configuration files for PHP when called via Apache and when called via the CLI.

For example, in Debian (at least), these are in `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` and `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini`, respectively.

The fact that you manually declared `imagick.so` in apache2/php.ini might not mean anything - most distributions have some other way of managing PHP modules, and can often automatically enable the extension for you, so it might have already been added.

I'd suggest looking up how your linux distribution manages PHP extensions (for Debian and Ubuntu, it uses a command called `php5enmod`, which needs to be called via `sudo`), or else just manually edit `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` or similar to be up to date.

Comment: Awesome, I'll take a look at that

Comment: That fixed it, thank you so much! I never noticed that there was a folder for `cli` in `/etc/php5/`